# Free / Trial Microsoft Exchange Server with owa access in web

Tags: exchange

Do you know any free or trial microsoft exchange server hosting with Outlook web access support for testing purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think almost any hosted provider would have a trial program.  Microsoft does:

http://www.microsoft.com/online/business-productivity.mspx

(scroll down for trial link)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to the Microsoft Exchange site that has a few different options to try out:

http://www.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/en/us/try-it.aspx

Answer (score 0):

https://r2.uctrial.com/register.aspx is the direct link that will let you sign up for a 7-day trial.